# advantage of namespace collections vs separate collections

Tags: mongodb, namespaces

I'm reading MongoDB's [data modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) documentation and have a question about namespaced collections.

The example they give uses a **logs** collection

```
{ log: "dev", ts: ..., info: ... }
{ log: "debug", ts: ..., info: ...}
```

And they say

> ***If the total number of documents is low*** you may group documents into collection by type. For logs, consider maintaining distinct log collections, such as **logs.dev** and **logs.debug**. The logs.dev collection would contain only the documents related to the dev environment.

I wondered what they meant about the total number of documents being low, but then I found the docs for *MongoDB limits*, which made it make sense.

So my question is, if there are these limits on namespace collections, what advantage is there to using them instead of just using brand new collections, like **logs_dev**
and **logs_debug**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing special about collection names that include a `.`; collections named `logs_dev` and `logs_debug` behave the same as ones named `logs.dev` and `logs.debug`.  They're all completely independent collections.

What I believe the quoted documentation is *trying* to convey is in a use-case like logging you can either put all your related docs in a single collection (where the docs are differentiated by a field like `type` in the example), or put them in separate collections.  And if you do put them in separate collections, consider using namespace-style naming to help make it clear that the collections are loosely related.

Comment: Thank you. The same docs state: *"A single <database>.ns file stores all meta-data for each database. Each index and collection has its own entry in the namespace file, MongoDB places limits on the size of namespace files."* So when they say "<database>.ns", the ".ns" part is actually just any collection name?

Comment: Alright, thanks again. Still the ***"If the total number of documents is low"*** part is confusing. Maybe they're referring to the number of categories of documents being low, like **dev** and **debug**? Anyway, I appreciate your help.